# $L^2$-based Sobolev spaces on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the space of Schwarz functions, and let $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the space of tempered distributions.

Define the Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{ u \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n): \langle \xi \rangle^s \hat{u} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \} $, for $s$ real, where $\langle \xi \rangle = (1 + |\xi|^2)^{1/2}$, and $\hat{u}$ is the Fourier transform of $u$. These are all Hilbert spaces.

Let $t \leq 0$. I want to know if the following holds: if $u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\langle x \rangle^t u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$. A proof outline, if the result is true, will be useful.

Comment: For integer $s$ this follows from the product rule, for fractional $s$ you can probably interpolate between the integer cases.

Comment: What is $\langle x\rangle ^t$? Why should that product even by square integrable?